# Create list of {x,f(x)} pairs

Tags: mathematica

How can I do this in Mathematica:

```
r=Range[0,20,0.13];
fr = HeavisideTheta[r];
data = somecoolfunctionsinmathematica[r,fr]
```

So that data now is in the form useful to `Fit`: `{{r_1,fr_1},{r_2,fr_2},...}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to use `Table` if you prefer it to `Map`:

```
Table[{i, HeavisideTheta[10 - i]}, {i, 0, 20, 0.013}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it, albeit syntactically a bit... involved (but I've seen a lot worse):

```
data = Table[{r[i], HeavisideTheta[10-r[i]]}, {r[i], Range[0, 20, 0.013]}]
```

Comment: `Map` will do it: `{#,HeavisideTheta[10-#]}&/@Range[0,20,0.013]`

Comment: Also `Transpose[{#, HeavisideTheta[10 - #]}]&[Range[0, 20, 0.013]]`...

Comment: Funny how the (IMHO) much worse pops up in comments under my answer :)

Comment: That's alright. IMHO taking a procedural approach when functional methods are available is a bit of a step backwards, but whatever, right?